# How to determine Signalled state of Win32 Event?

Tags: c++, winapi, events

I have an auto-reset event object created like this:

```
handle = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);
```

...and (for some unit testing purposes) I want to check if it's signalled at a certain point. I'm aware of the 'correct' way of using events - this is purely for a diagnostic harness.

For a manual reset event I can just use...

```
bool signalled = WaitForSingleObjectEx(handle, 0, true) != WAIT_TIMEOUT;
```

...but for auto-reset events that has the side-effect of resetting them. I guess I could try this, but I have a feeling that there should be a less dangerous way...?

```
bool isSignalled(HANDLE handle)
{
  bool signalled = WaitForSingleObjectEx(handle, 0, true) != WAIT_TIMEOUT;

  // warning - event is now reset. Maybe need to wrap this in a critical section or similar?

  if (signalled)  
    SetEvent(handle);

  return signalled; 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with the function you provide?

Comment: @RedX - the event becomes temporarily unsignalled, which could cause issues with other threads. It might need to be wrapped in a critical section or something similar, which feels like I'm overcomplicating things. I've added a code comment to show the 'danger area'

Comment: @Roddy what about this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx if you pass the same event as both handles it might do what you want.

Comment: Hmm... I think you're not even guaranteed that the thread calling isSignalled() is even the first to see that the event was signalled (regardless of manual or auto reset events). Assuming there is actually another thread doing "real work" and not just the one testing for the event to be signalled and the one that does signal it.

Comment: @RedX: SignalObjectAndWait - that signals first, then waits. So it's in the wrong order, and risks spuriously signalling a waiting task...

Comment: @Christian.K - You're right. I'm only planning to use "isSignalled" in unit tests, so maybe I can live with the race condition concern.

Comment: @Roddy - Yeah. I was just concerned about your tests failing "randomly" because of this. But, of course, given care and all, it could be useful.

Comment: This is kind of a useless function (particularly in the case of synchronization primitives) in that the result is immediately invalid - another thread can set (or reset) the event right after you check if it is set.

Comment: @Luke : That's true for almost ANY function in a multithreaded system. It's the context that you use it in that matters. In my case, (unit test code) it's definitely useful.

Comment: Your code may be fine as-is: If no thread was waiting the entire time you do your check, no harm done. If a thread did come in during the time you've 'taken' the event, it will wait for a short amount of time, but then be released as soon as you do your signal. So seems that the only negative consequences is that some threads may end up waiting slightly longer than had your test thread not been checking the event state. There may be a timing impact; but it doesn't look like there's a correctness/logic impact.

Comment: You haven't given enough context to determine a better solution.  In any case, I'm not a fan of using functions that modify state to get state; in older versions of Windows using the system clock applet actually modified the system time even if you didn't hit Apply or OK (yikes).  I would switch to a manual reset event (or some combination of synchronization primitives if that's not possible); this is a timing bug waiting to happen.

Comment: Also, I would explicitly check for WAIT_OBJECT_0 instead of considering the event as signaled if WaitForSingleObject returns anything other than WAIT_TIMEOUT. Otherwise you will return true for signaled when you get status WAIT_FAILED, which is probably a corner case you want to handle differently. Good Luck.

Comment: MS WinObj utility is apparently able to show event state in a non-destructive way. Does anyone have an idea of how WinObj manages to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a simple way to do it.  You could "mock" the event for testing purposes.

Wrap the event in an C++ object, and change all the code to use its methods.

```
class MockEvent {
  public:
    MockEvent () : m_handle(::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL) {}
    ~MockEvent () { ::CloseHandle(m_handle); }

    BOOL Set() { return ::SetEvent(m_handle); }

    DWORD Wait(DWORD timeout = INFINITE) {
      return ::WaitForSingleObject(m_handle, timeout);
    }

  private:
    HANDLE m_handle;
    // Do not implement copy or assignment:
    MockEvent(const MockEvent &);
    MockEvent &operator=(const MockEvent &);
};
```

Then you'll want to use some sort of reference counted pointer that can be passed around and copied the way the original HANDLE can be:

```
typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<MockEvent> MockEventPtr;
```

Replace all your code that uses the raw HANDLE with a MockEventPtr.

```
// Original code:
HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, true, false, NULL);
// Becomes:
MockEventPtr pEvent(new MockEvent);

// Original code:
SetEvent(hEvent);
// Becomes:
pEvent->Set();
```

And so on.

Now, for your diagnostic harness, you can extend MockEvent to keep track of the state and expose a method to show the current state.

```
class MockEvent {
  public:
    MockEvent () :
        m_handle(::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL),
        m_signaled(false) {
      ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs);
    }
    ~MockEvent () {
      ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs);
      ::CloseHandle(m_handle);
    }

    BOOL Set() {
      ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
      m_signaled = true;
      BOOL result = ::SetEvent(m_handle);
      ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
      return result;
    }

    DWORD Wait(DWORD timeout = INFINITE) {
      ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs);
      DWORD result = ::WaitForSingleObject(m_handle, timeout);
      if (result == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
        m_signaled = false;
      }
      ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs);
      return result;
    }

    // The result of this may be obsolete by the time you get it.
    bool IsSignaled() const { return m_signaled; }

  private:
    HANDLE m_handle;
    bool m_signaled;
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;
    // Do not implement copy or assignment:
    MockEvent(const MockEvent &);
    MockEvent &operator=(const MockEvent &);
};
```

This is untested code.  In real code, I'd wrap the CRITICAL_SECTION, too.  Note that the result of IsSignaled may be obsolete the moment you get it, if another thread changes the state.  I'm assuming this is for testing code that will check at a time when the state should be a certain way.

Answer (score 5):

Update:

The Coffee has kicked in, and I was wrong!

Using WaitForSingleObject with a timeout of zero to determine if an event has been signaled WILL cause the signal to be cleared if the Event is signaled (and its an AutoReset event). You can verify this by simply calling WaitForSingleObject twice in a row.

---

A **waiting thread has to be released** before an Event that is intialized for AutoReset will reset.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682396%28VS.85%29.aspx)

When you call WaitForSingleObjectEx with a timeout of zero, your thread does not become a waiter.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687036(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687036%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> If dwMilliseconds is zero, the
>   function does not enter a wait state
>   if the criteria is not met; it always
>   returns immediately.

Comment: So you're saying that a WaitForSingleObjectEx with a timeout of zero won't cause an an autoreset event to reset? Unfortunately that's not the way the OS behaves.... I think you're reading too much into the MSDN docs.

Comment: Thats what the docs say, but also thats the intended mechanism to determine what state an event is in. I'll go code a simple test app to make sure the docs are sane. Perhaps the bAlertable being set to true is causing the event to signal - but this is easy enough to verify.

Comment: I think, the wait state has something to do with thread switching not with changing state of an event.